# @font-face - Letter A not displaying correctly

Tags: css, font-face

Would anyone know why the letter A is showing incorrectly inside Chrome on Windows only? All other browsers it works! Even chrome on Mac. Heres a screenshot and heres the URL: http://new.leicesterymca.co.uk/hire/our-spaces/

[image]

Here's my font-face code:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'cheap_pineregular';
    src: url('fonts/cheap_pine_regular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('fonts/cheap_pine_regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/cheap_pine_regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('fonts/cheap_pine_regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/cheap_pine_regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('fonts/cheap_pine_regular-webfont.svg#cheap_pineregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'cheap_pine_sanssans';
    src: url('fonts/cheap_pine_sans-webfont.eot');
    src: url('fonts/cheap_pine_sans-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/cheap_pine_sans-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('fonts/cheap_pine_sans-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/cheap_pine_sans-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('fonts/cheap_pine_sans-webfont.svg#cheap_pine_sanssans') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
```

Comment: Have you tried the `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;` style?

Comment: Try temporarily removing the references to `woff` and `woff2` file types in the `@font-face` declaration.

Comment: Would that just be: body {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
} ? Ive just tried that but it docent seem to effect the error

Comment: That doesnt seem to work either Jamie... Ive deleted all reference but its still showing the error

Comment: I also tried this: @font-face {
  font-family: 'cheap_pine_sanssans';
  src: url('fonts/cheap_pine_sans-webfont.svg#cheap_pine_sanssans') format('svg');
}

} after I read something online... but no joy

Comment: I suspect it is dodgy font files. I just downloaded the `ttf` and installed it, and while it doesn't have that issue, it does look as though someone has done a _very_ bad job of creating that font in Illustrator.

Comment: Ah ok - I will try and get a different version of the font if I can and see if that fixes it

Comment: If you want to get around it, type everything that uses that font in CAPITAL LETTERS, or apply `text-transform: uppercase;` to each element that uses it. The capital A seems fine.

Comment: Ah good spot Jamie! That will do the trick - thanks for that :) I guess if its an uppercase font only there should be no reason for using lowercase! Thanks.